# Start Unicorn using ssl in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, unicorn

I'm migrating my rails app (still in development) from Thin to Unicorn. My app uses `config.force_ssl = true`.

When using Thin I could just write:

```
thin start --ssl
```

My question is: What is the equivalent way to start Unicorn with ssl in development?

Answer (score -2):

If I correctly understood your question, you're trying to run unicorn on port 443.

This is a bad idea.

Instead, to achieve the same goal, I would suggest, run unicorn on an unprivileged port (above 1024), or better on a unix socket, and switch Nginx before, passing all static stuff directly trough nginx, and the rails stuff, trough unicorn.

I know this doesn't answer your question, but for the user, it will work exactly the same, with some benefits when your app server (unicorn) crashes, for example a nice rendered 502 error page served via nginx instead of a plain network error message seen in the browser of your users.

You can with this solution run X different applications on the same port, with different subdomains. a must have for a development machine with many projects.

Comment: The original question explicitly mentions that @uri is looking for a solution in development. While your advice is good for a production environment, the `thin start --ssl` command is really handy (in development) and an equivalent on Unicorn would be nice to know about.